# How to limit the number of open forms?

Tags: c#, mdi

I have a `Main` form, which is MDI, and it has many child forms.

I want to limit the number of forms that can be open at once - e.g. no more than 8 forms open at a time.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is a very broad question, you must include more details.

Comment: How is this question more complicated than a) maintaining a static field which is incremented every time you open a form, and b) checking that field's value where a form is opened and prohibiting the operation if the value is too high (i.e. `8` in this case).

Comment: it is an inventory system in which i want the sales or purchase form should have limit that maximum 8 form can be opened at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MDI properly, then just check the Length of the `MdiChildren` collection in the Main MDI Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MdiChildren.Length < 8)
    {
        Form child = new Form();
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.Show();
    }
}
```